# Openlayers Custom Control: "Uncaught TypeError: setTarget is not a function"

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm currently working on a floor plan using the npm version of the OpenLayers library (v4.6.4) and wrote some custom controls for the map overlay.

After realizing that hovering over some custom controls will also trigger the `forEachFeatureAtPixel` hover function I implemented for specific features, I decided to place all map controls in containers outside of the map to prevent the hover trigger when an overlay element is in front of the feature.

Doing so with the basic controls of OpenLayers by adding the `target` parameter works fine. However, that doesn't seem to work with my custom controls. When calling my custom controls with a target parameter, the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setTarget is not a function at RotateLeft._ol_control_Control_ (control.js?8790:70)
```

The mentioned line in `ol/control/control.js` looks as follows:

```
if (options.target) {
  this.setTarget(options.target);
}
```

I don't think that there's an error in the `control.js`, because the standard controls work just fine with the `setTarget` function.

Here's one of my custom control functions (it adds a button for rotating the view counterclockwise):

```
/**
 * Import OL classes
*/
@import ol from 'ol';
@import Control from 'ol/control/control';

/**
 * Import view variable from app
*/
@import {view} from '../../app';

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {ol.control.Control}
 * @param {Object=} opt_options Control options.
*/
export function RotateLeft(opt_options) {
  let options = opt_options ? opt_options : {};

  let rotateLeftButton = document.createElement('button');
  rotateLeftButton.setAttribute('title', 'rotate left');
  rotateLeftButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-undo"></i>';

  let handleRotateLeft = function() {
    view.animate({
      rotation: view.getRotation() + (-Math.PI / 2),
    });
  };

  rotateLeftButton.addEventListener('click', handleRotateLeft, {passive: true});
  rotateLeftButton.addEventListener('touchstart', handleRotateLeft, {passive: true});

  let element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'ol-rotate-left ol-unselectable ol-control';
  element.appendChild(rotateLeftButton);

  Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target,
  });
  ol.inherits(RotateLeft, Control);
}
```

It looks similar to the example given on the [OpenLayers example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html).

And adding it to the map the same way I added the standard controls:

```
map.addControl(new RotateLeft({
  target: document.getElementById('control-rotation-left'),
});
```

I can't find anything on the internet or here on StackOverflow that handles a similar problem. Does anyone of you have any idea what may cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the call to ol.inherits outside your RotateLeft function:

```
export function RotateLeft(opt_options) {
  let options = opt_options ? opt_options : {};

  let rotateLeftButton = document.createElement('button');
  rotateLeftButton.setAttribute('title', 'rotate left');
  rotateLeftButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-undo"></i>';

  let handleRotateLeft = function() {
    view.animate({
      rotation: view.getRotation() + (-Math.PI / 2),
    });
  };

  rotateLeftButton.addEventListener('click', handleRotateLeft, {passive: true});
  rotateLeftButton.addEventListener('touchstart', handleRotateLeft, {passive: true});

  let element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'ol-rotate-left ol-unselectable ol-control';
  element.appendChild(rotateLeftButton);

  Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target,
  });

}
ol.inherits(RotateLeft, Control);
```

OpenLayer's inheritance system requires that you declare which class your new control inherits from when the new class is declared. It's this ol.inherits call that attaches all the Control methods onto your RotateLeft class, as you were doing this in your RotateLeft function the Control methods - specifically setTarget - aren't available when Control.Call is called, and Control.Call expects setTarget to be available on this.

Comment: Oh dangit. What a stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing out >_<